# In UIPageViewController, when "pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController"get called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I try to display photos in `UIPageViewController`. Firstly I display my photos in a collection view and then tap one photo to enter page view. When I'm in page view, however, if I scroll the currently photo(to right or left), I find that both `pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController` method will be called(by calling NSLog I found it).

Should just one of the two methods be called once?  I am quite confused by this and have big trouble updating my photoNumber for displaying the photo I want.

Here is my page view code:

```
#import "PhotoPageViewController.h"
#import "PhotoViewController.h"

@interface PhotoPageViewController ()
@property (nonatomic)NSInteger previousPhotoNumber;
@end

@implementation PhotoPageViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.dataSource = self;
    self.delegate = self;

    self.numberOfPhotosInCurrentAlbum = [Photo numberOfPhotosInAlbumWithName:self.albumName inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    PhotoViewController *currentPhotoViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoContentViewController"];
    currentPhotoViewController.photoNumber = self.currentPhotoNumber;
    currentPhotoViewController.albumName = self.albumName;
    currentPhotoViewController.context = self.context;

    currentPhotoViewController.ppvc = self;
    currentPhotoViewController.numberOfPhotosInCurrentAlbum =self.numberOfPhotosInCurrentAlbum;

    [self setViewControllers:@[currentPhotoViewController]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:NO
                  completion:NULL];
}



#pragma mark - Page View Controller Datasource

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (self.currentPhotoNumber > 0) {
        NSLog(@"in before section: current photo %lu", self.currentPhotoNumber);

        PhotoViewController *photoBeforeCurrentPhoto = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoContentViewController"];
        photoBeforeCurrentPhoto.photoNumber = self.currentPhotoNumber - 1;
        photoBeforeCurrentPhoto.albumName = self.albumName;
        photoBeforeCurrentPhoto.context = self.context;
        photoBeforeCurrentPhoto.ppvc = self;

        self.previousPhotoNumber = self.currentPhotoNumber;
        self.currentPhotoNumber--;

        return photoBeforeCurrentPhoto;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (self.currentPhotoNumber < self.numberOfPhotosInCurrentAlbum - 1) {
        NSLog(@"in after section: current photo %lu", self.currentPhotoNumber);
        PhotoViewController *photoAfterCurrentPhoto = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoContentViewController"];
        photoAfterCurrentPhoto.photoNumber = self.currentPhotoNumber + 1;
        photoAfterCurrentPhoto.albumName = self.albumName;
        photoAfterCurrentPhoto.context = self.context;
        photoAfterCurrentPhoto.ppvc = self;

        self.previousPhotoNumber = self.currentPhotoNumber;
        self.currentPhotoNumber++;

        return photoAfterCurrentPhoto;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

`PhotoViewController` is the view controller to display photo.

Can anyone give me some advice about the usage of `UIPageViewController`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both methods are called to load the next and previous view controllers for seamless scrolling,

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Those datasource methods are queried by the page view controller for the data it needs to show for the respected view controller i.e for a view controller after the current one and/or the before one the current view controller.

Comment: When I'm scrolling, if I stop on the way to next photo or scroll back, the view will still be the current one. That's fine. However, even though I didn't finish the whole scroll, those two methods were stilled called and my photoNumber was updated, so next time I scroll to next or previous photo, it will skip the real next(or previous) photo(because of the updated photoNumber). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`UIPageViewController` uses these bellow method for getting the back and front ViewController.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Though its weird but yes its a known issue. Every time it calls Before and After method to get VC. It there is no next VC then it returns nil and if there is no previous VC the `datasourceDelegate` return nil, otherwise it return the index of VC.

In `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`, there is a function named :

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers;
```

Look at this it might help to get the current or next/previous viewcontroller from `pendingViewControllers` array.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Is "setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:" always called by system automatically? Can I override this method in code?

Comment: @Reggie Yes, you can.

Comment: If I override this method in code, when this method will be called? After I start scrolling? Or? And what should I supply in this method? (I am new to iOS, thanks for your patience)

Comment: Once I thought I would answer your question directly but you'll learn a lot if you read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:

Comment: You can have a look at this setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: method in the above link

Comment: @Reggie Welcome. If your problem is solved then you should accept my answer.